# Dragging an image rendered on Canvas with a mobile device causes the image to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I'm making an app that draws images on canvas with Fabric.js.
For tablets and smartphones, if you pan the drawn image by dragging, the image disappears.
I will paste a GIF image that shows the current situation.

[demo GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR1RZ.gif)

I want to prevent images from disappearing by dragging panning even in browsers other than PC.
Please let me know if there is any other option to do this way.

The code is as follows:
By pressing the “Run code snippet”, you could see how it works.
When you upload an image, a "pan" button will appear on the canvas and below the canvas.
Press the "pan" button to pan the image.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

$("input").on("change", function (e) {
    var fr = new FileReader(e);
    fr.onload = (e) => {
        input(e.target.result);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
});

var input = function (url) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (oImg) {
        canvas.setWidth(450);
        var resizeScale = canvas.width / oImg.width;
        oImg.scale(resizeScale);
        canvas.setHeight(oImg.height * resizeScale);
        canvas.clear();
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        canvas.selection = oImg.selectable = false;
        $("#show").show();
        canvas.hoverCursor = "default"
    });
};

$("#pan").click(function () {
    canvas.hoverCursor = "crosshair"
});

canvas.on("mouse:down", () => {
    var panning;
    if (canvas.hoverCursor === "crosshair") {
        panning = true;
    };
    canvas.on("mouse:move", e => {
        if (panning) {
            const delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
            canvas.relativePan(delta);
        };
    });
    canvas.on("mouse:up", () => {
        panning = false;
    });
});
```

```css
html {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 550px;
}

input {
    margin: 5%;
}

#show {
    display: none;
}

canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
        <input type='file' accept='image/*' />
        <div id="show">
            <canvas id="c"></canvas>
            <button id="pan">pan</button>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a mobile device, the event passed into `mouse:...` listeners is not a `MouseEvent` but rather a [`TouchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent). It has a different interface than that of a `MouseEvent` and therefore you cannot access a `movementX` property. You can calculate the delta x/y yourself via something like this:

```
let panning
let prevX
let prevY
canvas.on("mouse:down", (e) => {
  panning = true
  if (e.e instanceof TouchEvent) {
    const {clientX, clientY} = e.e.touches[0]
    prevX = clientX
    prevY = clientY
  }
})

canvas.on("mouse:move", e => {
  if (panning) {
    let delta
    if (e.e instanceof TouchEvent) {
      // we're on mobile
      const {clientX, clientY} = e.e.touches[0]
      delta = new fabric.Point(clientX - prevX, clientY - prevY)
      prevX = clientX
      prevY = clientY
    } else {
      // we're on desktop
      delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY)
    }
    console.log(delta.x, delta.y)
    canvas.relativePan(delta)
  }
})

canvas.on("mouse:up", () => {
  panning = false
})
```

Here, I'm checking what kind of event was passed (via `e.e instanceof TouchEvent`) and calculate the `delta` accordingly. You might not need this if you only work with mobile devices.